# Correct way to pass string array member to MVC WebApi controller

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm starting with AngularJS and trying to pass a JSON object with a strings array member to an MVC WebApi GET method, but I cannot let my WebAPI controller receive a correct value for it. Probably I'm missing something obvious, could anyone suggest a solution? In JS, my call is like:

```
$http({
    url: "/api/test",
    method: "GET",
    params: {
      //...
        fields: ["one", "two"]
    }});
```

On the server side, here is the corresponding model:

```
public sealed class MyModel
{
    //...
    public List<string> Fields { get; set; }
}
```

And finally the controller's signature:

```
public dynamic Get([FromUri] MyModel model)
```

When I inspect model, I find that Fields is an array with only 1 item, which is right the "raw" JSON string, e.g. contains *["one","two"]* (square brackets and quotes included), rather than an array with the 2 items one and two. Is it possible to fix this?
Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

try with creating a client side JavaScript model object with one field as 'fields' of type array and set the fields.

```
var myObj = {}
myObj.fields = [];
myObj.fields.push("one")
myObj.fields.push("Two")
```

then pass the object to get method of WebApi.

```
$http({
url: "/api/test",
method: "GET",
data: myObj});
```

i think , this should work.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it does not work. I think the correct way of placing these data in the query string is using the params property rather than data, which is for posting. If I try with data, I simply get a null.

Answer (score 0):

try 'POST' and check capitalization of your MyModel fields/properties eg ( [f/F]ields)
plus check if you are passing one MyModel or an array of MyModels and update your webApi method signature.

I had a case few days back where I posted the C# class as a string.

```
// C# class
public class PeronSerachCriteria {
    public string surname, firstname, active;
    public int pageIndex, pageSize;
}

//C# web service method accepts post, passed in as a string
public Object[] Search(string criteria) {
    var ser = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    var x = ser.Deserialize < PeronSerachCriteria > (criteria);
}


// Angular.js service method
this.search = function(peronSerachCriteria) {

    var d = $q.defer();

    var postData = {
        criteria: JSON.stringify(peronSerachCriteria),
    };

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: apiurl + '/Search',
        data: postData,
        cache: true,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        d.resolve(data.d);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        d.reject(status);
    });
    return d.promise;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but I should stick to GET for this, in order to comply with the general RESTful architecture on the server side. The controller returns a list of items with GET, the details on an item with GET + id, and has methods for POST (=add new item) and PUT (=update item). I'm putting parameters in the GET query string because I'm going to use ng-grid, which requires me to send paging info, sort info (with a couple of string arrays for fields and descending/ascending order), and filtering info.